# PHPのGDで、画像をクロップして出力する

Tags: php

以下のようなコードで、正方形の画像を出力したいのですが、うまくいきません。

```
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($user["img"]);
                $width  = imagesx( $image );
                $height = imagesy( $image );
                if ( $width >= $height ) {
                    //横長の画像の時
                    $side = $height;
                    $x = floor( ( $width - $height ) / 2 );
                    $y = 0;
                    $width = $side;
                } else {
                    //縦長の画像の時
                    $side = $width;
                    $y = floor( ( $height - $width ) / 2 );
                    $x = 0;
                    $height = $side;
                }
                $thumbnail_width  = 100;
                $thumbnail_height = 100;
                $thumbnail = imagecreatetruecolor( $thumbnail_width, $thumbnail_height );
```

var_dumpで中身を見ると、resource(12) of type (gd)と表示されます。

正方形に画像を出力するには、どうすればいいでしょうか。

詳しい方、ご教示ください。

Answer (score 1):

画像Aの一部分を画像Bにコピーするには、`imagecopy` 系の関数を、その中でもサムネイル生成のように拡大縮小を伴う場合は `imageresized` もしくは [`imageresampled`](http://php.net/manual/ja/function.imagecopyresampled.php) を使います。

またGDの画像リソースは `var_dump` では確認できませんから、[`imagepng`](http://php.net/manual/ja/function.imagepng.php) や `imagejpeg` などを使って一般的な形式としてファイルや標準出力（ブラウザ）に書き出します。

まとめると、こんな感じでしょうか。

```
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($image_path);
$image_w = imagesx($image);
$image_h = imagesy($image);

$src_wh = min($image_w, $image_h);
$src_x = floor(($image_w - $src_wh) / 2);
$src_y = floor(($image_h - $src_wh) / 2);

$dest_wh = 120;
$dest = imagecreatetruecolor($dest_wh, $dest_wh);

imagecopyresampled(
    $dest, $image,
    0, 0, $src_x, $src_y,
    $dest_wh, $dest_wh, $src_wh, $src_wh);

// ブラウザに出力する
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($dest);
```